# SQL troubles with LOWER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a Problem using LOWER in SQL with my SQL Server 2008r2 I think I have a misunderstanding of the usage of lower , I'am always getting the same error Incorrect syntax near ','

```
INSERT INTO [ch-s-0008180].HolidayTracker.dbo.HtUser(FirstName,LastName,Email,UserName,AdAccount,AdDomain)
SELECT u1.firstName,u1.lastName,u1.email,'CH'+(LOWER(LEFT(u1.firstName,2))+(LOWER(LEFT(u1.lastName,3)),'EUROPE\'+(LOWER(LEFT(u1.firstName,2))+(LOWER(LEFT(u1.lastName,3)),''
FROM HolidayTracker.dbo.HTUser u1
    LEFT JOIN HolidayTracker.dbo.HtUser u2 ON u1.firstName = u2.FirstName AND u1.lastName = u2.LastName AND u1.email = u2.Email
```

thanks for help and fast answer

Comment: Also, was the backslash after `EUROPE` meant to be there?

Comment: @Jerry yes it there should be a backslash

Comment: It is much easier to spot problems in your SQL if you formatt it which makes it more readable. As you see in the answer below the SQL is nicely formatted which makes it easier to spot the extra bracket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have extra `(` before `LOWER`. Here's the modified query.

```
INSERT  INTO [ch-s-0008180].HolidayTracker.dbo.HtUser(FirstName,LastName,Email,UserName,AdAccount,AdDomain)
SELECT  u1.firstName, 
        u1.lastName, 
        u1.email, 
        'CH' + LOWER(LEFT(u1.firstName,2)) + LOWER(LEFT(u1.lastName,3)), 
        'EUROPE\' + LOWER(LEFT(u1.firstName,2)) + LOWER(LEFT(u1.lastName,3)),
        ''
FROM    HolidayTracker.dbo.HTUser u1
        LEFT JOIN HolidayTracker.dbo.HtUser u2 
            ON  u1.firstName = u2.FirstName AND 
                u1.lastName = u2.LastName AND 
                u1.email = u2.Email
```

*the colors of the code are messed up. `\` in `EUROPE` doesn't escape `'`*

Answer (score 0):

You do not close the bracket properly.

`'CH'+(LOWER ...,'' FROM`